# Sending Notifications at Pre-defined Time Not Working

Tags: android, calendar, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I read several questions here, and have a similar one as well. Non of the answers on another questions manage to solve the issue unfortunately. I know how to create a notification on Button click, yet I failed to create a notification for a specific time. My goal in the following code snippet was to create a notification at 19:00 every day. Here is the code snippet:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    setAlarm(calendar);
}

public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar) {

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alertIntent, 0);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                   24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Receiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    createNotification(context, "Blabla", "Blablablabla", "Alert");

    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg,
                                  String msgText, String msgAlert) {

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clear_dayicon)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText("msgText")
            .setTicker(msgAlert);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 // only ones I called after started working with notifications and stuff

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<service android:name=".Receiver2" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter> <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" /></intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"/>
```

Some help would be super appreciated. Since I'm a beginner, I need someone to show me my mistakes. Otherwise, I can't spot them no matter how many docs I read. This code looks fine to me :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

   setAlarm(calendar);
}
public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar) {
  boolean alarmNoActive = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("ALARM"), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

    if(alarmNoActive){
        Intent itAlarm = new Intent("ALARM");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,itAlarm,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

In the manifest put this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

In application:

```
  <receiver
        android:name="path of the BroadcastReceiver.Receiver"
        android:label="BroadcastReceiverAux">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ALARM" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: .getService() to .getBroadcast() was the issue I guess. Thanks for the improvements.